# Questions regarding sharedPreferences (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am experimenting around with Kotlin's `sharedPreferences`, however I cannot seem to get the updated value to stick.

```
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt("numbers",1).apply()
    val textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)
    textview.text = sharedPreferences.getInt("numbers",0).toString()
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        editor.putInt("numbers",2).apply()
        textview.text = sharedPreferences.getInt("numbers",0).toString()
    }
```

In the code above I set the initial value of the `sharedPreference` to 1, upon clicking the `button` the value will be updated to 2 and displayed.That works fine however when closing the app and reopening it, the value reverts to 1. Is there a way to permanatly keep the updated value?

Comment: Where and when are you putting the 1? Every time your app starts?

Comment: It is all in the `onCreate` method in the `MainActivity`, 1 is the initial value I set to the `getSharedPreferences`

Comment: I have came across this method `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, but I can't seem to find any decent examples in kotlin

Comment: You better do not set an initial value at all. Beter use the 1 as default value for getInt() instead of that 0 you use now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it to that value every time you open the activity, since `onCreate()` is called every time it opens. You should check if the value is already set, and if it is, skip that line of code.

```
if ("numbers" !in sharedPreferences) {
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putInt("numbers",1).apply()
}
```

By the way, there is an extension function for editing without having to call apply and `editor.` repeatedly:

```
if ("numbers" !in sharedPreferences) {
    sharedPreferences.edit {
        putInt("numbers",1)
    }
}
```